# How to add Mouse Bites or V-Groove to PCB In Altium?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, altium

I know mouse bites are more used to snap off one of many of the same boards in a panelized array, but I'm hoping to put mouse bites to snap off part of the same board if that's possible.

Is there just a standard for how far apart you put centers of drill holes?  Is there a standard diameter for the holes?

V-groove could work as well.

Comment: If you have IPC membership, it seems the topic is discussed in IPC-2221B.

Comment: Here's an [article on PCB arraying](http://pcdandf.com/cms/fabnews/9058-panelization).  Inside is a dimensioned drawing for a breakaway tab (although the resolution of the drawing leaves a lot to be desired).

Answer (score 8):

I had one project with an L shaped board. The PC assembly house wanted me to keep the inner corner of the board in place so that it was better supported by the rails through the pick and place machine. So I used mouse bites to connect the two sections together but to later have that inner corner removed when the boards went to functional testing.

Here is a picture showing the board (red outline) and the breakaway inner corner (green outline).

[image]

Here is the detail of the mouse bite design from the board fabrication drawing.

[image]

Notice that the breakaways are used in conjunction with routing that is performed using a cutter bit that is 100 mils in diameter.

Comment: I normally use a 2D CAD program for creating my board FAB drawings. The tool of choice these days is the free tool named DraftSight which is an AutoCad clone that offers DWG and DXF compatibility.

Comment: +1.  What CAD software were these drawings made in?

Comment: @NickAlexeev - DraftSight. Autocad could be used as well but DraftSight is free.