# How to create a break away to cut the board?

Tags: pcb, panelize

I am not a expert with Eagle 9.6 but I created a nice PCB. A friend of mine is going to assemble the part with a pick and place machine.

He asked me to enlarge my PCB to be able to fix the board and then cut this extra PCB. Exactly as we can see in that picture:

[image]

But I absolutely have no idea how to have this empty space with some small "contact" which will be broken, as we can see above.

Any advice how to proceed will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _bpard, thans, exactely..._ please take the time to spell check and fix typos. "P&P place machine" - P&P stands for "pick and place" so that translates to "pick and place place machine". The breakaways you are asking about are commonly called "rat bites" or "mouse bites." Here is a related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/92496/2028

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is done with something called a [vertical score](https://www.pcbuniverse.com/pcbu-tech-tips.php?a=1) or scoring for the breaking portion. To make an irregularly shaped PCB, usually this is done with the board outline file, expanding the board and then creating cutouts in the board file.

[image]
Source: https://www.pcbuniverse.com/pcbu-tech-tips.php?a=1

In the past I've created another layer in my cad and gerber file for the vertical scoring and lines where I want the scoring done (which should match up dimensionally with the other layers ie same scale and position as to where you want the cut)

Work with the PCB manufacturer on these special processes as they will need to know which files are the scoring and outline files.

If your simply trying to create a panelized design, then this tutorial for eagle might help: http://diy.viktak.com/2013/02/tutorial-panelizing-pcbs-in-eagle.html

Another thing to note is many board houses will create panelization for a small fee, so if that is your object of your design, then ask the board house about panelization